# Test parameters before using them or use try except

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some utility functions that will be used several times and I would like your opinion if it's better practice to test the input as I do in the following function or use `try` `except` or both are OK?

```py
# return element(s) of a list if there's an exact match
def get_element_in_list_if_match_exact(element, list_of_elements):
    if isinstance(element, list) and isinstance(element, str):
        # if element is exact match in list_of_elements
        return [c for c in checklist if c in words]

    MyLog.write("Invalid data type (get_element_in_list_if_match_exact_str)")
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl. But note that "better practice" is opinion-based and element is unlikely to be *both* a list and a string.

Comment: Thanks, I know it can be a string too, it was just an example.